# Lookup field on order object to flow to related list

Tags: apex

I have created a custom lookup field "Related_Commercial_order__C" on the csord__Order__c object.

I need to create a related list and the records selected in lookup window should get added to the related list.

Please help on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The question is somewhat unclear, but from what I understand, you want a related list of type `Commercial_order__C` to appear on your `csord__Order__c` records. If that's the case, I think you need to do this the other way around.

You need to add a field of type `Lookup(csord__Order__c)`  on the `Commercial_order__C` object. Then you can go to a record of type `csord__Order__c` and click related. It will show related `Commercial_order__C` objects there.

Let's talk about two standard objects as an example: accounts and contacts. If you want a related list of contacts to appear on each account record, you don't put a contact field on the account page layout. Instead, you put a field of type `Lookup(Account) on the contact page layout.